# Finding a Formula for $M^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Okay I need help finding a formula for the entries of $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. (My formulas should not contain complex numbers.)

The matrix $M$ is $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 8 \\ -8 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$

How I went about it was thinking about diagonalization in which case, using the  $PD^{n}P^{-1}$ method

I got $P$ in $PDP^{-1}$ by solving that
$\lambda_1= -4+8i$ with the respective eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} -i \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$
which leads me factoring out the $i$ out giving  $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + i\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ which means $P$= $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and its inverse, $P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $

I solved for $D$ as

$D$ = $4\sqrt{5}\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\arctan(2)+\pi) & -\sin(\arctan(2)+\pi)  \\ \sin(\arctan(2)+\pi)  & \cos(\arctan(2)+\pi)  \end{bmatrix}$

Now I tried to squish everything into $PD^{n}P^{-1}$ and checked to see if the formula I made up is equal to $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 8 \\ -8 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$ but it turns out it doesnt.. can anyone help?

I suspect it might be my $P$ value since I checked D and is indeed that   $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 8 \\ -8 & -4 \end{bmatrix} = $ $4\sqrt{5}\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\arctan(2)+\pi) & -\sin(\arctan(2)+\pi)  \\ \sin(\arctan(2)+\pi)  & \cos(\arctan(2)+\pi)  \end{bmatrix}$

Thanks

Comment: Isn't $D$ supposed to be a diagonal matrix, with the eigenvalues as the entries on the diagonal and zeroes everywhere else?

Comment: Its a complex eigenvalue/vector I kind of copied it from watching the video  here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bPwL30PBwM&t=617s

Comment: Why should your formulas not contain complex numbers?

Comment: it says in the webwork question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed by diagonalizing (but do heed Eric Towers' comment). Alternatively, if you're not so familiar with complex matrices you can, for real numbers $a$ and $b$ not both $0$, find a real $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta = a/\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$ and $\sin\theta = b/\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$, and then write
$$
M = \left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
    a & -b \\
    b & a \\
  \end{array}\right]
= \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} \left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$
Since scalars commute with rotation,
$$
M^{n} = (a^{2} + b^{2})^{n/2} \left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
    \cos(n\theta) & -\sin(n\theta) \\
    \sin(n\theta) & \cos(n\theta) \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega=1+2i$ and let $R_n= \Re \omega^n.$ Since $M=-4C,$ where $C=$
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $M=(-4)^nC^n,$ where
$$C^n=\begin{bmatrix} R_n &  {1\over 2}R_{n+1}-{1\over 2}R_n \\ -{1\over 2}R_{n+1}+{1\over 2}R_n & R_n \end{bmatrix}.$$
When you verify this formula by induction, you'll need that
$$R_{n+2}-2R_{n+1}+5R_n=0,$$
which follows from
$$\omega^{n+2}-2\omega^{n+1}+5\omega^n=\omega^n(\omega^2-2\omega+5)=\omega^n(0)=0.$$

Comment: TYPO  It should be $M^n=(-4)^nC^n$